# Correct or best way to declare variable in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following code, which option (A or B), are the best way to declare a variable which will be assigned in the following if statement.

Alternatively, is there a better way than A or B.

```
(A) List<Dollars> amount;
(B) var amount = new List<Dollars>();

if (vortex is null)
{
    amount = this.seven.Map<List<Dollars>>(twelve);
}
else 
{
    amount = rendered;
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that your List is going to get populated after declaration there is no need to initialize it prior to that. I'd tend to use Option `A` in this case.

Comment: I prefer option **A** - because it's just **clearer** and more obvious what you're trying to do. If someone else needs to read and understand your code - make it as **crystal clear** as possible for them - don't just use `var` everywhere because you're too lazy to spell out the actual, concrete type....

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the post of Microsoft docs [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables):

> The var keyword can also be useful when the specific type of the
>   variable is tedious to type on the keyboard, or is obvious, or does
>   not add to the readability of the code.

Look at the line -

- **The var keyword can also be useful when the specific type of the variable is tedious to type on the keyboard, or is obvious, or does
  not add to the readability of the code.**

One example where var is helpful in this manner is with nested generic types such as those used with group operations. In the following query, the type of the query variable is IEnumerable>. As long as you and others who must maintain your code understand this, there is no problem with using implicit typing for convenience and brevity.

**The disadvantage here is**, the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C# documentation generally uses var only when it is required.

Your answer is, no. There is no

> best way to declare a variable

There is: *what type of way suits your needs the most*.